How to hide Posts of subcategories in WordPress Website
I enabled the Breadcrumbs feature on my WP website. It worked well, it listed all categories properly. But one issue bothered me, that all posts would be displayed in a category. I just want to display the posts that belong to the current category excluding all in the subcategories.
I've tried two methods but failed to achieve it.
Firstly, I installed a Code Snippets plugin to add a PHP snippet
function exclude_subcategory_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'include_children', false ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_subcategory_posts' );

And then I enabled it to be executed everywhere on my website for tests. No changes happened.
Secondly, I tried to edit the temple file to display archives. I found the below code snippet and then got some advice from ChatGPT4. It gave a parameter string for "taxQuery". But that string can't be inserted into the code properly.
<!-- wp:query {"queryId":0,"query":{"perPage":10,"pages":0,"offset":0,"postType":"post","order":"desc","orderBy":"date","author":"","search":"","exclude":[],"sticky":"","inherit":true,"taxQuery":null,"parents":[]},"align":"wide","layout":{"type":"constrained","wideSize":"100%"}} -->

Could you please give me an appropriate and easy way to achieve it? I'm a WP newbie. Thanks a lot.

The reason the initial snippet didn’t work is that include_children only controls whether child categories are considered, but your setup required targeting posts strictly within the current category. By adding a tax_query with include_children => false, this snippet directly filters posts based on the category you're viewing, excluding posts from subcategories. It explicitly queries for posts in the current category alone.

@RomanM thanks. I tried new code function filter_out_children( $query ) {   if ( is_main_query() && is_category() && ! is_admin() ) {      $qo = $query->get_queried_object();      $tax_query = array(        'taxonomy' => 'category',        'field' => 'id',        'terms' => ! is_null($qo) ? $qo->term_id : null,        'include_children' => false      );      $query->set( 'tax_query', array($tax_query) );   } } . Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.
